# re: fbml phase out

Tags: fbml, out, phase

I have apps in fbml

just received an email saying they will no longer work on june 1

what do i do?

they say I have to create new apps in html

surely there is another easier way to transition the apps

any help/advice is appreciated on the best way to do this

thanks

tony

Answer (score 0):

It hasn't been possible to create an FBML app since March 2011, and the complete removal is on the roadmap for June 6th and was flagged back in [September 2011](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/568/)
There's no 'transition' guide so to speak, just reimplement your app's content in an iframe, and if you need interactive content, follow the documentation for the currently supported APIs

If it's just static content you want to display on a page tab, etc, here's some 3rd party apps that you could use instead of reimplementing your own app:

- WildFire iFrame app
- Static iFrame Tab
- Static HTML Plus
- Involver iFrame app
- Tabpress